# Guest Account Missing from Login Screen

Tags: guest-account

I have an iMac running 10.13.6.  I have enabled the Guest account in Users & Groups within System Preferences, with Parental Controls unchecked, and Access to Shared Folders unchecked.  However, the guest account does not appear on the Login Screen.

** FileVault is NOT turned on **

Any ideas on how I can make the Guest Account reappear on the login screen?

Comment: show us the settings

Comment: In the end I decided it would be easiest to just reimage the computer.  As such, I cannot provide you any of the original settings.  How would I have done that, btw? Screenshots?

Comment: take pic by phone then download via Bluetooth and post here